# Correct way to use MarkerClusterer with $.ajax call

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to use the library "MarkerClusterer" ([Google page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/marker-clustering?hl=fr)) to cluster my markers on Google Maps via the API.

I tried to implement it to my actual code that seams to work but when I zoom out/in the cluster disapear. And when i refresh the page the clusters numbers are not the same. Why ?

Here is what i want to do with this API :

[image]

[jsfiddle : my code](https://jsfiddle.net/2e2z1fsq/)

```
$.ajaxq (qyName, {
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json'
    }).done(function( data ) {
                var address = getParameterByName('address', this.url);
                var index = errorArray.indexOf(address);
                try{
                    var p = data.results[0].geometry.location;
                    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(p.lat, p.lng);

                    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: latlng,
                        map: map
                    });

        // Add markers to array
        map.markers.push(marker);

        markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, map.markers, {
            imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'
        });

});
```

What i'm doing wrong ? Thx for the help.

Comment: Are you missing your variable `marker` or is that a Copy + Paste typo?

Comment: @Lixus : it's fixed :) error of copy/paste

Comment: Are you just adding one marker per ajax call? If so you are making new clusters every call, you should more like create a new one outside of it, with an empty array as parameter, and inside your call do `markerCluster.addMarker()` see if that works

Comment: The choice for your title is poor.  MarkerCluster works fine, you need to correct way to use it.

Comment: There is only one marker on your fiddle.  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: Sorry for the title, i forget to edit after creating my «ask». And in my exemple there is more than one marker, look beter geo ! My var placesObject contains fews lat and lng. So i don't understand your reply and the downvote...

Comment: @Peacefull I am trying to debug yoru issue, but noticed the markers are not showing up anymore in the jsfiddle code you linked. I am not sure why it stopped showing up?!?!

Comment: {error_message: "You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API.", results: [],…}
error_message
:
"You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API."
results
:
[]
status
:
"OVER_QUERY_LIMIT"

Comment: @Nick Timmer My API key have reach the limit of request per day. Maybe if you have an another key you can try. Just swap the key in my code. Thx for trying helping me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well i answer to my question because i found the solution thanks to @Lixus for puting me in the right way !

We must set the new MarkerClusterer outside the ajax call and set it with an empty array for markers. Then we call the method .addMarkers() with our markers array.

```
var mcOptions    = {gridSize: 50, maxZoom: 15, imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'};
var mc           = new MarkerClusterer(map, [], mcOptions);
```

Then in our ajax call we do something like that :

```
 marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map,
            icon: icon,
            // Custom property to hold the filters options, it'a used below to filter the markers
          });

          // Add markers to array
          map.markers.push(marker);

          mc.addMarkers(map.markers);
```

[Working jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p10cyqfh/)